# Filtrando por filhos vazios

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, expressões-lambda, linq-to-entities

Tenho duas entidades (`TipoDeRequerimento` e `TipoRequerimentoSituaçãoAcademica`) na minha consulta. Hoje eu consigo fazer um filtro para trazer os *Tipos de requerimentos* que tenham uma determinada situação acadêmica pré-cadastrada. Agora preciso que esse filtro retorne também os Tipos de requerimento que não tenham *Situação Acadêmica* informada, ou seja, para um determinado requerimento que eu cadastrei e não informei Situação Acadêmica.

Segue o código da consulta:

```
IList lista = null;
using (var bll = new TipoRequerimentoRepository(empresa))
{
    var pLista = bll.Query(p => p.Descricao.Contains(filtro) || filtro == "")
        .Where(p => categoriaID == 0 || p.CategoriaID == categoriaID)
        .Where(p => situacaoAcademicaID == 0 || p.TipoRequerimentoSituacaoAcademica.Any(x => x.AlunoSituacaoAcademica.AlunoSituacaoAcademicaID == situacaoAcademicaID))
        .Where(p => p.Ativo == true)
        .Select(p => new
        {
            id = p.ID,
            name = p.Descricao,
            prazoDias = p.Prazo,
            valor = p.ValorUnitario,
            Gratuito = p.Gratuito
        });
    lista = pQtdeRegistros > 0 ? pLista.Take(pQtdeRegistros).AsNoTracking().Distinct().ToList() : pLista.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
return lista;
```

No filtro tentei colocar um código que filtrava o `TipoRequerimentoStuacaoAcademica == NULL` mas não obtive êxito. Caso alguém possa me ajudar, agradeço muito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se, por exemplo, definirmos que `situacaoAcademicaID = -1` retorna os requerimentos que não possuem Situação Acadêmica informada, você poderá implementar assim:

```
var pLista = bll.Query(p => p.Descricao.Contains(filtro) || filtro == "")
    .Where(p => categoriaID == 0 || p.CategoriaID == categoriaID)
    .Where(p => situacaoAcademicaID == 0
                || situacaoAcademicaID == -1 && p.TipoRequerimentoSituacaoAcademica.Count == 0 
                || p.TipoRequerimentoSituacaoAcademica.Any(x => x.AlunoSituacaoAcademica.AlunoSituacaoAcademicaID == situacaoAcademicaID))
    .Where(p => p.Ativo == true)
    .Select(p => new
```

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou retorna a lista vazia também.

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que `TipoRequerimentoStuacaoAcademica` é uma coleção de `TipoDeRequerimento`.

Tente usar `!p.TipoRequerimentoStuacaoAcademica.Any()` ao invés de `p.TipoRequerimentoStuacaoAcademica == null`.

Comment: Também tentei ele retorna vazio sem nada na lista

Comment: Funcionou com um ajuda de um parenteses ficando dessa forma `.Where(p => (!p.TipoRequerimentoSituacaoAcademica.Any() || p.TipoRequerimentoSituacaoAcademica.Any(x => x.AlunoSituacaoAcademica.AlunoSituacaoAcademicaID == situacaoAcademicaID)))`